# Twilio video conection time

Tags: node.js, twilio, javadoc

I have an application with twilio video in nodejs. I wanted to know, how to delimit the video connection time.

**Two users connect to a videoconference for 30 minutes, after this time the connection is deleted.**

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

This is not something that the Twilio Video API or SDK handles for you, so you will need to build this functionality yourself.

What you would need to do is when a room is started, schedule an event for 30 minutes later that, when fired calls on the [REST API to complete the video room](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/api/rooms-resource#complete-room).

The simplest way to do this is with a `setTimeout` in Node.js. But those events are kept in memory and are vulnerable to server restarts. Alternatively, you could use a library like [Agenda](https://github.com/agenda/agenda) which can schedule future events for you and is database backed.